# Node Express Route dynamic method

Tags: node.js, express, routes, router

I want the method to be dynamic

```
const method = METHODS?.[config.method] ?? 'get';
const endpoint = config.endpoint;
const router = express.Router();
```

This works

```
app['post'](endpoint, execute);
```

This is not working

```
app[method](endpoint, execute);
```

Answer (score 0):

I declared wrong type.

Changed it from

```
export interface RouteConfig {
  endpoint: METHODS;
  method: string;
  authorizer?: string;
  handler: string;
}
```

to

```
export interface RouteConfig {
  endpoint: string;
  method: METHODS;
  authorizer?: string;
  handler: string;
}
```